# Копирование данных из одного xml в другой

Tags: xml, java, dom

Проблема состоит в следующем: мне нужно найти в первом файле по имени все теги и заменить их на содержимое второго файла. Найти теги не проблема, проблема возникает при попытке записать данные из второго файла. Постоянно выскакивает DOMException. При копировании не целого файла, а одного тега проблемы не возникает.

```
        Document mDoc1 = docBuilder.parse(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/1.xml"));  
        Document mDoc2 = docBuilder.parse(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/1.xml"));
    NodeList nodes = mDoc1.getElementsByTagName("company");
    Node root1 = mDoc2.getDocumentElement();
    Node root2 = mDoc2.getDocumentElement();
    mDoc1.adoptNode(root2);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < nodes.getLength())
    {
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        String s = node.toString();
        node.appendChild(mDoc2.importNode(root2, true));
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Поднимаю вопрос.

Comment: А не модифицируйте дерево, а стройте новое. В этом случае даже возможно использование sax парсера, что может дать хорошее ускорение.